# How to increase curl GET request url size limit?

Tags: java, php, url, curl, get

Here is the background of a product architecture i'm working on.

I am working on product where front-end is in PHP and back-end is in JAVA.
JAVA works as a service and PHP uses `curl` library to call java services.

I'm using GET Request to call java services.

It was working perfectly, but i faced an issue when URL is too long (in my case URL is almost 2,00,000 characters long).

i searched about [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/features.html) and i found that there is no limit for url length in curl.

also when curl is executed i checked curl error number `curl_errno()` and it returned 0. [curl Returns the error number or 0 (zero) if no error occurred.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)

so i can't figure out what can be the issue, also it is issue at JAVA side or PHP side ?
also how can i increase GET request size limit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java application server (or any intermediate entity that processes the request, like a firewall) may limit the url size. So, try to pass data on the body of the request, not on the url.

Comment: i cant.. :(
Product code is so much complex. i cant change it to POST request now. i have to use GET request only.

Comment: The configuration of the max url length depends on the server/firewall/etc you use. But two million characters seems too long, anyway.

Comment: compress your data?, seems like switching to post would be much easier

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey : compress url data in GET request ? how ?

Comment: @Andres: in my case do i have to change the configuration of JAVA server as curl showing no error ?

Comment: URL size isn't limited only by webserver configuration. Browsers also limit that value. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: `$compressed = gzcompress('Compress me', 9);` then add it to your GET values, you obviously will need to uncompress it in your other app

Comment: @PareshBalar Yes, here you can learn how to do it on Tomcat: http://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat

Comment: @victorantunes He's using curl, so the browser probably's not the problem.

Comment: @victorantunes: i'm not using browser as its curl library. browser limit wont be issue in my case.

Comment: @Andres : thanx.. i think this will solve my problem.. will try this. hope this will solve my problem.. :)